# missing annotation package in spring-modules-validation-0.8a source file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-validator

I have downloaded 
**spring-modules-validation-0.8a-sources.jar and spring-modules-validation-0.8a-
sources.jar.** 
In spring-modules-validation-0.8a-sources.jar there is package name annotation with package
orde as
 **org.springmodules.validation-> bean->config->loader->annotation.**
But in spring-modules-validation-0.8a-sources the package name annotation is missing.I am confused why it is so.As i am trying to write some custom annotaion and i want to take some quick refernce with spring annoation for bean validation with some source files.For eample there are MaxLength,MaxSize and its implementation part in jar files .But it is missing in source files.Thanks

Comment: Did you find the package name annotation. I have the same problem. or How can you handle it?